# relationship many to many in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, many-to-many, relationship

hello i have this model in my project, University 1 - N City N - N Carreer
so, a carrer can appear in many cities and a city has got many carrers.

my models:

```
University.rb
  class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sedes
  end

City.rb
   class Sede < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :university
      has_and_belongs_to_many :carrers
   end

Carrer.rb
  class Carrer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
  end
```

then i create a migration "CitiesCarrers"  to save un database realtionship N-N

```
  class CreateCitiesCarrers < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
       create_table :cities_carrers, :id => false do |t|
         t.references :city
         t.references :carrer
       end
       add_index :cities_carrers, :city_id
       add_index :cities_carrers, :carrer_id
    end
  end
```

so, how i do to display in Cities json, the carrers which are relationship with it?

```
    in my CitiesController

    def index
      render json: {cities: City.all, carrers: Carrer.all }, methods: {:university_id :carrer_id }
    end
```

i put there ":carrer_id" and app crush, but if i draw it when i show the cities, carreers are in blak.

can us help me? thanks

Comment: Comma missing before :carrer_id, just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```
render json: { City.all, include: [:carrers] }
```

If you have a `@cities` instance variable from the index method, you would do this...

```
render json: { @cities, include: [:carrers] }
```

And, for performance reasons, do this

```
City.include(:carrers) # 'include' to avoid n+1 query.
```